# Install phpMyAdmin on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

So I've read through everything I can find via google and still no love, I'm unable to get PMA to connect to the CloudSQL servers.

I just keep receiving this error message when attempting to login:

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

here's my config currently:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = ':/cloudsql/<project-id>:<instance>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

I've tried changing the "connect_type" to tcp & switching out the host for the IP but no love.

I've also tried these variables for the "host":

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = ':/cloudsql/<project-id>:<instance>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '/cloudsql/<project-id>:<instance>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'cloudsql/<project-id>:<instance>';
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, i've been banging my head against a wall for a few days now.

**NOTE: I have added my project-id to the credentials for the CloudSQL instance and tested via PHP PDO that I can connect from the project to the database.**

Comment: That doesn't look like a legitimate host IP address or hostname. Double check that against what Google has provided in their documentation or ask their support folks to confirm your database server hostname/IP address.

Comment: Have you tried changing `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']`?

Comment: @Mars I have, I've tried many, many variations with no luck. I actually just ended up re-working SQLBuddy to work specifically on GAE. I just have to test it a bit more, once I'm sure it's solid I'll post it up on Git Hub.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that held me up for days (I can't even be ticked at myself, I have to laugh) When they say https://phpmyadmin-dot-myapp.appspot.com/ thats exactly what they mean. I automatically replaced -dot- with a . like phpmyadmin.myapp.appspot.com