# Cannot log in to the MySQL server error when logging into phpmyadmin with Google Cloud SQL on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

EDIT: Changed my question around as this is the real problem:

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine) Google guide to deploy phpmyadmin on Google Cloud SQL with Google App Engine.

I followed the tutorial and deployed phpmyadmin successfully to my App Engine however, when I try to log in with user: "root" password: [null] I get the following error:

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

Here is my config.inc.php file (taken pretty much verbatim from the guide). Is there something missing here?

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 * http://www.question-defense.com/tools/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<your-secret>'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-cloudsql-instance>';
$type = 'socket';

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/*
* Other settings
*/
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
?>
```

I also made sure to whitelist my IP address from which I am accessing phpmyadmin. Furthermore, I can successfully connect to the Google Cloud SQL instance using mysql from the command line so I know it's not a permission issue.

I also found these links here with a similar issue and tried them but they did not help me:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10027

[Install phpMyAdmin on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310948/install-phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine)

[How to trace mysql log in Google Cloud SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944383/how-to-trace-mysql-log-in-google-cloud-sql)

Comment: Did you authorize the App Engine app as described by https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appengine ?

Comment: @cflewis Yes. I just checked it. It was already authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem:

In the guide it says:

```
// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-cloudsql-instance>';
```

If you go to your Google Cloud SQL and view your GC-SQL instance, you will see that the instance ID is listed as

```
<your-project-id>:<your-cloudsql-instance>
```

So the mistake I made was doing this:

```
// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
    $host = '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-project-id>:<your-cloudsql-instance>';
```

When it should be

```
// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-cloudsql-instance>';
```

Hope this helps a noob somewhere!!!!!